# Send an AppointmentItem with HTML Body with Python win32com library

Tags: python, python-3.x, win32com

I'm trying to create an Appointment in Outlook 2007, with Python 3.
I am able to create a calendar with plain text body, but not a body with HTML text. There is no 'CreateItem.HTMLBody' property

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")

App = outlook.CreateItem(1) #olAppointmentItem


App.Subject = "Meeting with CEO"

#App.Body = 'Hi Tim, <br><br>Kindly attend the meeting.'   
App.HTMLBody = 'Hi Tim, <br><br>Kindly attend the meeting.'
App.Location = "Meeting Room 10"
App.Start = '2017-07-17 15:00'
App.Duration = 3
recipient='abcd@xyz.com'

App.MeetingStatus = 1
App.Recipients.Add(recipient)

App.Display()
#App.Send()
```

I have also tried using GetInspector.WordEditor, but that too just gives plain text.

```
Selection = App.GetInspector.WordEditor.Windows(1).Selection
Selection.TypeText ('Hi Tim, <br><br>Kindly attend the meeting.')
```

How can I go about this? Any tips?

Answer (score -1):

This should be helpful:-
[Send an AppointmentIthem with python win32com library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44437912/send-an-appointmentithem-with-python-win32com-library)

Another way to do it:-
http://www.baryudin.com/blog/sending-outlook-appointments-python.html

Comment: I have gone through them before, it doesn't address how to send an html body. That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: Maybe this then - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-using-python